# Electric field screening for arbitrarily formed charge

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics

if I have a not necessarily homogenous electric field of a charge distribution in an electrolyte and i want to find out what the electric field at some position in the electrolyte is. is there any equation that i could use to consider also electric screening by the ions, so that I will get a different electric field that is lowered by the screening?

So basically I am looking for an equation that takes an electric field or potential and gives me the screened one.